# Spinner Android Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, spinners

Bom dia estou criando um app, e preciso que ele tenho um spinner, que puxe os todos os dados de uma coluna do banco de dados.
Mas acontece que quando eu puxo ele trás os dados, mas só que ele faz o list view ficar em vários, em vez de jogar todos os dados em um só spinner. Só consigo fazer ele ficar certo, quando coloco dados fisicos no spinner.

```
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> list;
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(""); //Aqui eu coloco os dados fisicos... Eu quero puxar os dados de uma classe.
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(IdentificacaoActivity.this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

A classe que eu quero puxar é essa.

```
public class Identificacao {
private String cnpjcpf;
private String codigocondicao;
private String prazoentrega;
private String observacoes;
private String cnpjloja;
private String senhaacesso;
private String dataacesso;
private String horaacesso;
private String descricao;

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public String getCnpjcpf() {
    return cnpjcpf;
}

public void setCnpjcpf(String cnpjcpf) {
    this.cnpjcpf = cnpjcpf;
}

public String getCodigocondicao() {
    return codigocondicao;
}

public void setCodigocondicao(String codigocondicao) {
    this.codigocondicao = codigocondicao;
}

public String getPrazoentrega() {
    return prazoentrega;
}

public void setPrazoentrega(String prazoentrega) {
    this.prazoentrega = prazoentrega;
}

public String getObservacoes() {
    return observacoes;
}

public void setObservacoes(String observacoes) {
    this.observacoes = observacoes;
}

public String getCnpjloja() {
    return cnpjloja;
}

public void setCnpjloja(String cnpjloja) {
    this.cnpjloja = cnpjloja;
}

public String getSenhaacesso() {
    return senhaacesso;
}

public void setSenhaacesso(String senhaacesso) {
    this.senhaacesso = senhaacesso;
}

public String getDataacesso() {
    return dataacesso;
}

public void setDataacesso(String dataacesso) {
    this.dataacesso = dataacesso;
}

public String getHoraacesso() {
    return horaacesso;
}

public void setHoraacesso(String horaacesso) {
    this.horaacesso = horaacesso;
}
}
```

Preciso puxar pro spinner o codigocondicao e descricao.

Já tentei fazer isso para puxar, mas não vai...

```
Identificacao item = new Identificacao();
list.add(item.getCodigoCondicao +" "+item.getDescricao);
```

Mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode sobrescrever o método `ToString()` da sua classe `Identificacao`, e e criar um `adapter` do tipo `List<Identificacao>` ao invés do tipo `List<String>`, mas isso não deixa o projeto flexível na minha opinião..

Para isto, sugiro criar uma `classe` auxiliar e sobrescreva o método `ToString()`

```
public class ItemData<T> {

    private String mText = "";
    private T mValue = null;

    public ItemData(String text, T value) {
        this.mText = text;
        this.mValue = value;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(String mText) {
        this.mText = mText;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(T mValue) {
        this.mValue = mValue;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

No seu código basta fazer:

```
List<ItemData<Identificacao>> mLista  = new List<ItemData<Identificacao>>();

Identificacao item = new Identificacao();
//puxar os dados
ItemData itemData = new ItemData<Identificacao>(item.getCodigoCondicao +" "+item.getDescricao, item);
mLista.add(itemData);


mDataAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<ItemData<Identificacao>>(this.mContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    mLista);
mDataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);
```

Para obter o a ENTIDADE do `spinner` selecionado basta fazer um `cast` no `getSelectedItem()` do `spinner`

```
ItemData<Identificacao> item = ((ItemData<Identificacao>)spinner.getSelectedItem());

Identificacao identificacao = item.getValue();
```